# How to compile boost library for Nintendo DS Lite (arm none eabi g++ compiler)?

Tags: c++, boost, bjam, nintendo-ds, b2

I want to compile the c++ boost library for the NDS (on a Windows machine). I followed this tutorial: https://patater.com/boost-on-the-nintendo-ds/

This is my project-config.jam:

```
import option ; 

using gcc : 6.3.0 : arm-none-eabi-g++.exe ;

option.set keep-going : false ;
```

But when I run bjam, it hangs forever(actually not forever, but it has been running for more than two hours). Also, nothing is outputted to my output directory. How do I compile boost for the NDS?

EDIT:
To provide you some more details, this is what I did:

1. I downloaded Boost
2. I ran `bootstrap.bat`
3. I added `C:\devkitPro\devkitARM\arm-none-eabi\bin` and `C:\devkitPro\devkitARM\bin` to `PATH`
4. I changed `using msvc ;` to using `gcc : 6.3.0 : arm-none-eabi-g++.exe ;`
5. I ran this command in the boost directory: `b2 --toolset=gcc-6.3.0 --prefix=C:\devkitPro\boost threading=single link=static install`

Comment: in order for people to help we'll need more information and details

Comment: @user3299379 I updated my question, is there any more information I need to provide?

Comment: the more information you're able to provide the better. are you able to quantify forever? does it compile without boost? any other steps you're taking? are you using the same environment as the tutorial?

Comment: @user3299379 What do you mean with 'does it compile without boost'? Without boost, there's nothing to compile.